# change font size by select option in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

i need to change font size using function in JavaScript by select option

```
<label for="sel1">size of font:
                    <select class="form-control" onchange="size (this);">size of font:
                         <option onclick="size(4)">4</option>
                         <option onclick="size(8)">8</option>
                         <option onclick="size(12)">12</option>
                         <option onclick="size(16)">16</option>
                         <option onclick="size(20)">20</option>
                         <option onclick="size(24)">24</option>
                         <option onclick="size(28)">28</option>
                         <option onclick="size(32)">32</option>
                         <option onclick="size(36)">36</option>
                         <option onclick="size(40)">40</option>
                         <option onclick="size(44)">44</option>
                         <option onclick="size(48)">48</option>
                         <option onclick="size(52)">52</option>
                         <option onclick="size(56)">56</option>
                         <option onclick="size(58)">58</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
```

this function i think have error

```
    function size(n){
            var s=document.getElementById("demo");
            s.style.fontSize = n + "px";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function changeSize(n) {
    var s = document.getElementById('demo');
    s.style.fontSize = n.value + 'px'
}
```

```html
<label for="sel1">size of font:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1" onchange="changeSize(this);">
  <option>4</option>
  <option>8</option>
  <option>12</option>
  <option>16</option>
  <option>20</option>
  <option>24</option>
  <option>28</option>
  <option>32</option>
  <option>36</option>
  <option>40</option>
  <option>44</option>
  <option>48</option>
  <option>52</option>
  <option>56</option>
  <option>58</option>
</select>
<div id="demo">
DEMO
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not register onclick event on every option element. It is enough to set it to the select.

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="size(this);">size of font:
                         <option value="4">4</option>
                         <option value="8">8</option>
```

and your function:

```
function size(elm){
            var s=document.getElementById("demo");
            s.style.fontSize = elm.value + "px";
        }
```

and it is better to seperate the value and viewed text of the option, for example you may want to add extra information to the option in the future such as `<option value="4">4px</option>`